# how to use case in From sub query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle12c

```
SELECT Source.par_row_id,
      max(case when Source.Changed_Column= 'End Date' then str end) as End_Date,       
      max(case when Source.Changed_Column = 'Start Date' then str end) as Start_Date
      max(case when Source.Changed_Column = 'Name' then str end) as Name,
      max(case when Source.Changed_Column = 'LastName' then str end) as LastNAme
      LISTAGG(Source.Changed_Column, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Source.par_row_id) as EventChanges       
from (
--from (select Source.*, 'WAS: ' || Source.old_column_value,'' || ' NOW: ' || source.new_column_value) as str
--      from Source
--    ) 


select Source.*, ('WAS: ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Source.OLD_COLUMN_VALUE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') ||
                                      ' NOW: ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Source.NEW_COLUMN_VALUE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS')) as str
                  from Source
                 ) Source
            group by Source.par_row_id
```

The above works for date but name and lastname will be problem.

The problem is above will work when the date is coming old and new value other wise for other columns it will throw error.

In this above query I will get some values in varchar and some of them I need to convert in case, Is it possible to use CASE anywhere here, I have tried CASE in that commented line but its not working.

Fiddles available here, Anybody can check the working environment here - [FIDDLER](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=385d9f180e5db15793471c0844829f3f)

Comment: Your DB Fiddle works and has the correct logic.  I don't understand why you would want to change the data format of the column values.

Comment: Is it Posible you just forget the comma after "as Event_Delivery_Mode"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its because now the current value comes as varchar as it is from DB I want to change it to date format to do that I need case or something to match with normal varchar and this values.